# Racket, Error: Cannot reference an identifier before its definition

Tags: racket

The function should return `(set 'n0 'n1)` when `(get-backlinks '((n0 n1) (n1 n2) (n0 n2)) n2)` as input. But I got an error :

> n2: undefined;
>
> cannot reference an identifier before its definition**

Here is the code:

```
(define (get-backlinks graph page)
  (define (helper graph sets)
    (match graph
      ['() (list->set graph)]
      [`((,a ,b) . ,rst)
       (if (equal? b page)
           (helper rst (cons a sets))
           (helper rst sets))]))
  (helper graph '()))
```

I don't really understand where went wrong

Comment: You forgot to quote `n2` in the application `(get-backlinks '((n0 n1) (n1 n2) (n0 n2)) n2)`. it should be `(get-backlinks '((n0 n1) (n1 n2) (n0 n2)) 'n2)`. However, this still doesn't give the desired result, as it returns an empty set.

Comment: Note that the matching case `['() (list->set graph)]` is equivalent to `['() (list->set '())]`. The result is accumulated in `sets`, which you throw away.